# Insert html form and action page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables. I have inserted data into `data_types` through html form with action="insert.php".

But the problem comes how I will insert data into `data_table` through one single html form with action="insert1.php" .

Plz sugest me how will I complete the 2nd form. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

`data_types`

```
    id  title   
------  --------
     1  d1      
     2  d2      
     3  d3      
     4  d4      
     5  d5      
     6  c1      
     7  c2      
     8  c3      
     9  c4      
    10  c5      
    11  c6
```

`data_table`

```
    id  name    type_id  type_value  
------  ------  -------  ------------
     1  Tapan         1             2
     2  Tapan         2             0
     3  Tapan         3             3
     4  Tapan         4             8
     5  Tapan         5             0
     6  Tapan         6            12
     7  Tapan         7            14
     8  Tapan         8             0
     9  Tapan         9             0
    10  Tapan        10            17
    11  Tapan        11             0
```

Comment: Add the code for insert.php here. To insert the data into the other table, input your SQL queries in insert1.php.

Comment: create a form, insert the data. Sounds like you've done that once already for another table. It's difficult to understand what your problem is? What are you worried about, exactly?

Comment: @ ADyson How will I structure the `html form`  for 2nd table and also `sql query`?

Comment: do you have to enter a new row into data_type simultaneously as a new row in data_table? Or you just need to reference the type_id and allow user to select a valid value?

Comment: @ADyson I need to reference the type_id and allow user to select a valid value. I want to insert all the value with  reference the type_id in one html form. You may suggest me regarding the form structure.

Comment: make a dropdown list with all the types in it (which you have populated from the data_types table) so the user can see all possible values and choose from it. After that you just need a textbox for the "name" field and another for the "type_value" field (assuming that's also something which the user inputs?). The database will create a value for the "id" field when you insert the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may insert data into `data_table` in this way:

```
INSERT INTO data_table ( `id`, `name`, `type_id`, `type_value` ) VALUES
(1, 'Tapan', 1, 2), 
(2, 'Tapan', 2, 0), 
(3, 'Tapan', 3, 3), 
(4, 'Tapan', 4, 8)....
```